# Python: Logging in to a website

Tags: python, urllib

I found this code somewhere on stackoverflow for reddit. I tried to modify it for hackthissite.org:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import cookielib

# Store the cookies and create an opener to hold them
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

# Add our headers
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Tester')]

# Install the opener, changes the global opener to the one we just made
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# URL for authentification
auth_url = 'https://www.hackthissite.org/user/login'

# Parameters to send
payload = {
    'username': 'myUser',
    'password': 'myPass',
    'btn_submit': 'Login'
}

# Encode payload
data = urllib.urlencode(payload)

# Build request object (supplying 'data' makes it a POST)
req = urllib2.Request(auth_url, data)

# Make request and store in resp
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)

print resp
```

As far as I can tell I got the payload right, this is the login form on hackthissite.org :

```
<form id="loginform" method="post" action="/user/login">
<div id="innerlogin">
        <script type="text/javascript">var userclicked=0; var passclicked=0;</script>
        <p><input type="text" name="username" class="login" value="" onclick="if(userclicked==0){this.value='';userclicked=1;};" title="Username" /></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" class="login" value="" onclick="if(passclicked==0){this.value='';passclicked=1;};" title="Password" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Login" name="btn_submit" class="submit-button" /></p>
</div>
</form>
```

The response I get from the server is:

```
<addinfourl at 36515712 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x022D3DB0>>
```

How can I log in to the site?
What does the servers response mean in this case? (AddInfoUrl ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly recommend you simply take a look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and use that, instead. It makes this sort of thing almost trivial. For example, here's how you'd interface the site you mentioned:

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open("https://www.hackthissite.org/user/login")

br.select_form(predicate=lambda f: f.attrs.get('action') == '/user/login')
br["username"] = "myUser"
br["password"] = "myPass"
response = br.submit()

print response.read()
```

UPDATE: To explain this line:

```
br.select_form(predicate=lambda f: f.attrs.get('action') == '/user/login')
```

`select_form` takes either a `nr` argument, or a `name` argument, or a `predicate` argument. If you do `br.select_form(nr=1)`, this selects the second form on the page. If you do `br.select_form(name="foobar")`, this selects the first form named "foobar" on the page. Or you can give it a function which takes an `HTMLForm` object, and returns whether that should be the form to select.

In the above case I'm giving it a function which returns true if the `"action"` attribute of the form is `"/user/login"`. If you know the form's name or its position in the document, that's probably easier.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look!
Can you explain what this part does:
predicate=lambda f: f.attrs.get('action') == '/user/login'
I understand that I'm selecting the form from br that has action = "/user/login" but what does the predicate=lambda f mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

[`urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) returns a “file-like” object which is essentially a handle where you can read the response from. If you are just interested in the response text of the server, you can just call `read` on the response object:

```
print resp.read()
```

In addition, you also a few extra methods like `info` which gives you information about the response headers.